# How to replace spaces middle of string in Dart?

Tags: regex, replace, dart, flutter, whitespace

I have string as shown below. In dart trim() its removes the whitespace end of the string. My question is: How to **replace spaces middle of string** in Dart?

```
Example-1:

 - Original: String _myText = "Netflix.com.          Amsterdam";
 - Expected Text: "Netflix.com. Amsterdam"


Example-2:

 - Original: String _myText = "The dog has a    long      tail.  ";
 - Expected Text: "The dog has a long tail."
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Using RegExp like

```
String result = _myText.replaceAll(RegExp(' +'), ' ');
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case I had tabs, spaces and carriage returns mixed in (i thought it was just spaces to start)

You can use:

```
String result = _myText.replaceAll(RegExp('\\s+'), ' ');
```

If you want to replace all extra whitespace with just a single space.

Answer (score 0):

To replace white space with single space we can iterate through the string and add the characters into new string variable by checking whitespace condition as below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  String str = "Dart remove empty space ";
  String stringAfterRemovingWhiteSpace = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!str[i].contains(' ')) {
      stringAfterRemovingWhiteSpace = stringAfterRemovingWhiteSpace + "" + str[i];
    }
  }
  print(stringAfterRemovingWhiteSpace);
}
```

Originally published at https://kodeazy.com/flutter-remove-whitespace-string/